# Following a question

Tags: feature-request, support

Is there a way to "follow" a question (i.e. get a message in your Stack Exchange inbox whenever someone comments on or answers it)? If not, can that feature be added?

Answer (score 4):

[Isaac Moses answered](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/821) well; I'll add that if you mark a question as 'favorite' by clicking the star near it then you can follow edits and answers to it on [your 'favorites' tab](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1208/ari-a?tab=favorites) (and so can everyone else).

Answer (score 2):

Such a feature does not [currently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/179) exist.

Below is an alternative that gives you some of the functionality you want, using third-party tools. (I wrote it initially based on an incorrect assumption that you meant "email inbox" and present it now as a side point.)

---

Using [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS), you can subscribe to answers and (I think) edits to a question, but not comments. On the bottom-right of every question feed, there's an RSS link labeled "question feed." If you use an RSS reader such as [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader), you can put that link into it to get updates there. You can also sign up for an "[RSS to Email](https://www.google.com/search?q=rss%20to%20email)" service that will make the RSS feed into emails for you.

Comment: By "inbox" I meant the thing at the top right of the SE site, not my actual email.